# Collection и Collections

Tags: java, наследование, коллекции

Как мы можем использовать методы класса *Collectons* в наших коллецкиях *Java*, если мы нигде от него не наследуемся в иерархии коллекций?

Comment: что подразумевается под "не наследуемся в иерархии коллекций" ?

Comment: А как мы используем `System.out.println()`, если нигде не наследуемся от `System`?

Comment: Иначе сформулирую. В ArrayList есть метод sort. Он обозначен как @override. Но ArrayList  не наследует Collections.

Comment: @Artem,  аннотация **@Override** проверят, действительно ли метод переопределяет метод суперкласса, если нет - ошибка компиляции;  другими словами, если переопределяешь метод суперкласса - добавляешь **@Override**

Comment: Мы  не используем метод `sort()` класса `Collections` обращаясь к методу `ArrayList.sort()`.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что все методы класса **Collections** статические, экземпляр класса **Collections** создавать не нужно
+ при использовании коллекции нужно импортировать класс этой коллекции.
Например, при использовании ArrayList:

```
import java.util.ArrayList
```

Answer (score 0):

> В ArrayList есть метод sort. Он обозначен как @override. Но ArrayList не наследует Collections.

Это разные методы. `ArrayList.sort` это оверрайд метода `List.sort`. `Collections.sort` внутри себя вызывает сортировку конкретного списка. Вот кусок исходников:

**ArrayList:**

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    final int expectedModCount = modCount;
    Arrays.sort((E[]) elementData, 0, size, c);
    if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
    modCount++;
}
```

**Collections:**

```
/**
 * Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the
 * {@linkplain Comparable natural ordering} of its elements.
 * All elements in the list must implement the {@link Comparable}
 * interface.  Furthermore, all elements in the list must be
 * <i>mutually comparable</i> (that is, {@code e1.compareTo(e2)}
 * must not throw a {@code ClassCastException} for any elements
 * {@code e1} and {@code e2} in the list).
 *
 * <p>This sort is guaranteed to be <i>stable</i>:  equal elements will
 * not be reordered as a result of the sort.
 *
 * <p>The specified list must be modifiable, but need not be resizable.
 *
 * @implNote
 * This implementation defers to the {@link List#sort(Comparator)}
 * method using the specified list and a {@code null} comparator.
 *
 * @param  <T> the class of the objects in the list
 * @param  list the list to be sorted.
 * @throws ClassCastException if the list contains elements that are not
 *         <i>mutually comparable</i> (for example, strings and integers).
 * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the specified list's
 *         list-iterator does not support the {@code set} operation.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException (optional) if the implementation
 *         detects that the natural ordering of the list elements is
 *         found to violate the {@link Comparable} contract
 * @see List#sort(Comparator)
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    list.sort(null);
}
```

Comment: Минусатор, за что минус?

Comment: `ArrayList.sort()` действительно переопределяет `List.sort()`. `Collections` как бы сам по себе и использует метод `List`